# Honeymoon Trip: First Class & Economy mix on SQ & Star Alliance

Tags: air-travel, bookings, loyalty-programs, luxury, singapore-airlines

[Please skip to the question at the end if you don't want to read the entire situation.]

I'm planning my honeymoon far in advance because I will purchase Singapore Airlines's Round The World Trip using all of my miles obtained from business travel and credit card spending. My intention is to buy the 180K Economy RTW and the 360K First Class.

Here is the situation. My girlfriend likes to cuddle when we sleep and would prefer doing that in economy to sleeping alone in First Class. Plus, it will be our honeymoon, so we definitely don't want to be separated on the plane. Knowing that SQ first class is a generous apartment that can easily fit 2 people, I don't see a reason why I should buy 2 First Class RTW because she would end up visiting my apartment anyway.

Would it be possible to bring my girlfriend to the First Class apartment from Economy (except during take-off and landing, of course)? All the flights in my RTW itinerary are at least 6 hours. Any suggestions/comments would be much appreciated!

Comment: I know the apartment in Emirates allows you to bring someone to join from economy. Don’t know about Singapore. By the way you’ll catch some flack for even thinking to book economy for her with you in first. It should be the other way around. Enjoy your honeymoon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't think the order would be important, but will definitely take your advice!

Comment: One Mile At a Time has some [anecdotal experience](https://onemileatatime.com/can-your-travel-companions-visit-you-in-first-class/) in the comments (you may be able to find others on FlyerTalk). It seems to depend somewhat on the crew, and you're kind of putting them in an awkward position if they want to ask her to go back. A visit is one thing, while staying the entire flight, repeatedly across a RTW itineary, may be asking rather a lot. Their business model is not based around sharing first class with economy passengers. That said, their service is legendary, and they may be accommodating.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  It's a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, airlines will not allow passengers from Economy to come up to First, even if it is your honeymoon.  In addition to crew at the pointy end being generally vigilant about keeping the riffraff out, the seats are not built for two if there's turbulence etc.  And while most first class seats are pretty massive by cramped airplane standards, they're *not* "generous apartments"; at last check Singapore Airlines had a stiff surcharge (around US$2000) if you wanted to book an actual [Suite](https://www.roundabouttravel.com.au/editorials/inside-the-singapore-airlines-suites/) even on a First RTW.

There's an obvious alternative though: have you considered buying **two Business Class RTWs instead**?  At 240,000 miles each, the total cost comes out same.   Many airplanes have adjacent seats with dividers that can be lowered, and on some Singapore Airlines A380s [you can even convert two business class seats into a double bed](https://www.ausbt.com.au/singapore-airlines-new-a380-business-class-seats-are-a-double-bed).  In addition, First Class seats are a dying breed, you'll have many more airline & flight choices if you go with Business instead.

Comment: I agree with the business class recommendation, but I wouldn’t be so sure about the first part of your post. Many airlines even advertise the existence of an additional “seat” for visitors coming to your first class seat. Of course, don’t expect the visitor to get all the first class extras (meals, etc.).

Comment: @jcaron Those are meant for guests also traveling in First.  Etihad: *"you might want to invite a travelling partner **from First Class** to join you in your apartment for a meal or a meeting."* https://www.etihad.com/en-au/experience-etihad/flying-reimagined/first-class/

Comment: Thank you! I was leaning towards 2 Business Class bookings, but I just want to check if this First Class/Economy pair option works out or not since first class offers more privacy than the business double bed